# expand qgraphicsrectitem to cover complete scene and expand all children's in same proportion

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have created a QGraphicsView with a scene set on it with QGraphicsRectItem in it.

[fig-1]

[image]

I want that when I double click on the green rectangle marked with thick black border, the scene gets filled with only this rectangle and all its children also get expanded in same proportion.

So, when I double click , I should see something like this in complete view:

[image]

I have handled the double click event but do not know how to handle this.

Also, when I double click again, I get back to the previous state (as shown in fig-1)

Comment: Did you try QGraphicsItem::setScale()?

Comment: yes.. this did not work.... The idea is that there should not be any other item left on the scene except this particular item.

Comment: What's the problem with `QGraphicsItem::setScale()` ?

Comment: @Tomas : It does NOT remove the other parts of the scene. So, in my case as shown in fig-1 above, rectangles in quadrant 1 , 2 and 4 should be removed and the rectangle in quadrant 2 (as shown in fig 2) above should take the complete scene space.

Comment: Well, you can always hide the other parts with the `QGraphicsITem::hide()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states for [QGraphicsView::fitInView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-2)

> Ensures that item fits tightly inside the view, scaling the view according to aspectRatioMode.

So, assuming `pView` is your `QGraphicsView`and `this`is the rectangle you want to view, call fitInView from the overloaded double click event of `QGraphicsRectItem`: -

```
pView->fitInView(this);
```

---

Based on the comments that only the rect and its children should be visible, one option to guarantee this would be, on double-click, to create a separate scene, move the rect to the new scene and switch the view to the new scene.

Comment: No... this is not what I want.. it will fit in view, but other parts will still remain in the scene.. its just that  a zoom has been applied on that item...

The other items should not be shown...

Comment: @Nishant Sharma - What's the problem with having remained other parts in the scene if user doesn't see them?

Comment: @Tomas : with firInView, that particular item is fitted in view whereas other items are still there... From what I want, we want to give  a dive-in feature.

Comment: @NishantSharma, updated answer based on your comments.